# How to position image caption over and within a responsive image?

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="media">
  <img src="/img/sample.jpg">
  <div class="caption">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip.
  </div>
</div>
```

The size of the image will shrink/grow with the size change of the browser. The caption should be positioned over the image and within the boundary of the image. The width of the caption must change when the image size changes.

The image is large enough to hold the text. The image size is not known in advance. The image must retain original width when the browser's viewport width is larger than the image's actual width. I hope the caption is positioned at the bottom of the image.

If there is any css solution, that will be fantastic.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/P92Fs/7/

```
.media {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.media .caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! The .media width cannot be fixed because it changes too. I notice that the caption is clipped in your example when the image size changes.

Comment: May I know why you use "width: 100vmin; height: 80vmin;" for .media? In my case, the image size can be unknown in advance.

Comment: @curious1 The width/height is just an example. If the image size can't be know in advanced… you might have to use javascript.

Comment: the image is not responsive any more based on your updated css.

Comment: @curious1 What do you mean by "responsive", anyway?

Comment: By responsive, I mean the image shrinks when the viewport width is smaller than the image width and the image enlarges until the viewport width is large enough to hold the orignal image. Your earlier response is very close, but as you said the solution may need Javascript. Thanks!

Comment: @curious1 Oh. `img {max-width: 100%;}`

Comment: Interestingly, your solution works perfect in Chrome, but the image does shrink accordingly in Firefox or IE10 (Windows) when the browser shrinks.

Comment: @curious1 Weird. Just make `max-width` `width`, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this it should work perfectly.
http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/ygL64/

```
img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #ccc;
 position: relative;    
}
.caption {
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 200px;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

Comment: Change the location of the caption by left or top.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Like I said in the post, the width of the caption should change too when the image sizes changes.